# is there an easier way to convert 'curl_setopt' to wp_remote-post $args array?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, plugins, php-curl

I need to convert my functioning curl_exec() to a WordPress wp_remote_get()

I have tried several argument options, and I keep getting a 401

```
//CURL code 'this runs perfectly':
$endpoint = $this->_getApiEndpointForUser($username);
$authHeader = base64_encode($username . ':' . $apiKey);//
$this->curl = curl_init($endpoint);//
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ' . $authHeader));//
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/geotrust_global_ca.crt');
$payload = array('method' => $method, 'params' => $params, 'id' => $this->_generateRequestId(),);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $this->json_encode($payload));
$result = curl_exec($this->curl);

//wp_remote_post code 'This returns a 401':
$this->endpoint = self::_getApiEndpointForUser($username);
$authHeader = base64_encode($username . ':' . $apiKey);
$this->args['headers'] = array('Authorization: Basic ' . $authHeader);
$this->args['cookies'] = array();
$this->args['sslverify'] = true;
$this->args['sslcertificates'] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/geotrust_global_ca.crt';
$payload = array('method' => $method, 'params' => $params, 'id' => $this->_generateRequestId());
$this->args['body'] = json_encode($payload);
$response = wp_remote_post($this->endpoint, $this->args);
```

I am hoping to get a 200 response code when running this, but keep getting 401. Any help would be so much appreciated; I have been at this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

1. Weird, but turning the headers array into an associative array in wp_remote_post solved issue. On curl_setopt this isn't true.

   $this->args['headers'] = array('Authorization: Basic ' => $authHeader);